# Designer view not showing in Visual Studio windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I'm not sure why my designer bit of my Windows Forms is showing code instead of the actual design. It did before but I don't know what I did to change it. How can I change it back?

[image]

Comment: Ther probably is a designer error of some sort. Double check the designer code and make sure everything looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I am also a new developer and member. See where I have my mouse from the solution navigator menu? Open it will show you the form.

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply, I tried that (I clicked open with C# editor default) but it still comes up with the code?

Comment: hi amanda, there may be an object that is not available in the Form Designer section. You can check it from "Form.Designer.cs" file.